# clang: error: no input files in sublime text while coding in c++ on a MacBook

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, sublimetext3

I started c++ today using sublime text as my editor. I've never used sublime text, c++ or xcode before.

I was first getting an error, which I resolved using this:

https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/1569/how-to-solve-macos-git-xcrun-error-invalid-active-developer-path-library-developer-commandlinetools.

Now that I've cleared this error, I'm now getting another one
`clang: error: no input files`

My code is a simple hello world program. Can someone help me clear this?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    cout << "hello world";
}
```

Comment: What command are you running for compilation?

Comment: That error indicates that you're telling `clang` to compile something, but you didn't say what file to compile. Are you using a custom `sublime-build` file? If so, make sure the command line includes `$file` or similar. Also make sure that you've saved the file first - If you create a new tab and put some code in it and try to build without saving, it won't exist on disk and thus has no name.

Comment: @kiner_shah i'm using sublime text's command+shift+B, so that's the build and run command

Comment: @OdatNurd  i am saving the file first, still i'm getting the error. And i don't know what a sublime-build file is, this is my first time using sublime text.

Comment: @marshmallow. try compiling from the terminal.

Comment: I would expect that you need to use `clang++` the C++ compiler and not `clang` (the C compiler) for this source.

Comment: Are you compiling your .cpp file in your .cpp file directory?  If not, you're not in the proper directory. Just "*`cd your_cpp_file_directory`*", then try again.